# Git does not use SSH key for Github (Mac OS)

Tags: git, github, ssh, ssh-keys

I am trying to setup my git to let me clone/push/pull/... from and to GitHub in the terminal without entering my Username and Password, but I am getting this error:

```
❯ git clone https://github.com/Johannes-Krabbe/private-repo.git
Cloning into 'private-repo'...
Username for 'https://github.com': Johannes-Krabbe
Password for 'https://Johannes-Krabbe@github.com':
remote: Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021.
remote: Please see https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/getting-started-with-git/about-remote-repositories#cloning-with-https-urls for information on currently recommended modes of authentication.
fatal: Authentication failed for 'https://github.com/Johannes-Krabbe/private-repo.git/'
```

I followed both of the following tutorials:

- https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent
- https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account

When I run `❯ ssh -T git@github.com` I get this output:

```
Hi Johannes-Krabbe! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When using git via ssh you cannot use `https://` URLs, but specific ssh addresses instead. In your case use `git@github.com:Johannes-Krabbe/private-repo.git` to access your repository.